# Struts2 - passing action member variable as parameter using Annotation

Tags: struts2

In short i have an action class with a instance variable called bestTutorialSite. This variable can be passed to a JSP as per below:

```
<package name="tutorial1" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getTutorial" class="org.tutorial.struts2.action.TutorialAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">getTutorialPage</param>
            <param name="namespace">/tutorials</param>
            <param name="message">${bestTutorialSite}</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">getErrorPage</param>
            <param name="namespace">/tutorials</param>
            <param name="message">${bestTutorialSite}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="tutorial2" namespace="/tutorials" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getTutorialPage">
        <result>/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="getErrorPage">
        <result>/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

No problem using the XML way.
Question is how do i do that using Annotation since the annotated params requires constant expression (the instance variable bestTutorialSite is not a constant expression).

Further information:
success.jsp

```
<body>
  Success Page!!
<br/>
 <s:property value="$parameters['message']"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Results({
   @Result(name = "success", type = "redirectAction", params = {"namespace", "/tutorials", "actionName", "getTutorialPage", "message", "${bestTutorialSite}"}),
   @Result(name = "error", type = "redirectAction", params = {"namespace", "/tutorials", "actionName", "getErrorPage", "message", "${bestTutorialSite}"})
})
public class TutorialAction extends ActionSupport...
```

**Note**: As a dependency you will need the struts2 conventions plugin.
For further examples and reference please see: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Actionannotation

**Edit**: 
In Addressing the action name concern brought up in the comments.

Conventions uses action names separated with hyphens. That is we would not call an action *getTutorial* but *get-tutorial*.

The action *get-tutorial* may have an action class. As per your xml the action class is required to be in the root namespace. However the current namespace is `org.tutorial.struts2.action.TutorialAction` this will NOT be in the default namespace because conventions will search for packages with *struts2* or *action* and packages further down the hierarchy are interpreted as struts2 packages.

Thus conventions would interpret your `org.tutorial.struts2.action.TutorialAction` class as being in the `/action/tutorial` namespace. We should change the package name to `org.tutorial.myapp.action.GetTutorialAction` or something similar to avoid this issue.

Note, `Get` was appended to *TutorialAction* so struts would locate the action as `/get-tutorial`.

Views follow a parallel pattern to package names. As your current action stands you would need your view to be located at `/WEB-INF/content/action/tutorial.jsp` (conventions will also be able to identify freemarker and velocity views by the file extension). Also you can factor in the name of the result into the view, for instance `/WEB-INF/content/action/tutorial-success.jsp`, `/WEB-INF/content/action/tutorial-error.jsp`, and `/WEB-INF/content/action/tutorial-input.jsp` so if execute returns "success" you'll get the former and if "error" then the latter. Class names are of course camel case (as per Java naming conventions) however the views will be all lowercase and hyphens will appear between words.

A very useful technique is to create all input forms as "*-input.jsp", you can directly go to the view (bypassing the action class), for instance with an anchor defined as:

`<s:a namespace="/employee" action="person-input">Go to Person Input</s:a>`

If there is not a class called `PersonInput` or `PersonInputAction` (remember to don't have to put *Action* on the end) then the view will render as is, the view for the form will point at the Person Action, like so: .

If the validation of the form fails (returns input) then the Person action will try "person-input" first and you are thrown back at the form. This is very useful.

When using conventions the biggest need for annotations should be:

- reusing views
- Using a redirectAction to put you back someplace after taking an action. Perhaps a list after an update.
- less common: using a different result type (json, stream)

As such the @Result and @Results annotations are most common. @Action annotations typically appear when you try to buck conventions but remember you don't need to write annotations except to deviate from the expected. So you are literally making work for yourself.

One good use of action annotations is to declare multiple action methods in the same class (could be useful for certain crud operations for a single entity). I personally prefer a one class per action strategy but can appreciate this use of the action annotation, however as mentioned using it to produce action synonyms or override conventions I don't like.

To name your action other than conventions such as "getTutorial" you would say:

```
@Action(value="/getTutorial", 
    results={
       @Result(name = "success", type = "redirectAction", params = {"namespace", "/tutorials", "actionName", "getTutorialPage", "message", "${bestTutorialSite}"}),
       @Result(name = "error", type = "redirectAction", params = {"namespace", "/tutorials", "actionName", "getErrorPage", "message", "${bestTutorialSite}"})
})
```

As mentioned this isn't recommended.

Comment: Using XML, there is no action class for action name "getTutorialPage". You don't see a class attribute for the action name "getTutorialPage". It's more like a dummy action where a class definition need not be defined. How do i do that using annotation?

Comment: By the way, the params you showed doesn't work. The parameter message is not displayed in the JSP success.jsp using annotation (though it works using XML)

Comment: That is strange, my own struts2 application is passing parameters using annotations as shown here... you are right with regard to the action name being incorrect but I don't like to deviate from conventions defaults much.

Comment: See update... conventions is worth learning, it isn't hard to learn but you do need to know what is going on, then it will save you a lot of time. The point to the large update is that you don't just switch between xml and annotations but rather between xml and conventions and conventions is overridden with annotations.